# Getter for a read-only variable in C

Tags: c, initialization, getter

I am writing a library. This library has an `init()` function that initializes some internal variables. These variable must be accessible from outside, but only in read-only.

Because I am working on an embedded device, it is too expansive to have a real *getter* function.

What good solution can I use other than these two ones (assuming they are both bad solutions):

Using an `inline` getter (where `_internal_parameter` cannot be `static`):

```
inline int get_parameter() { extern int _interal_parameter; return _internal_parameter; }
```

Using a `const` (where the `const` variable is not really protected):

```
// lib.c
void init() {
    *(int*)&parameter = get_value_for_parameter();        
}

// lib.h
extern const int parameter //!< initialized by init();
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the first solution?

Comment: Anybody that reads the header file can do access and modify `_internal_parameter` since it's not a static variable restricted to `lib.c`.

Comment: I think in this situation practicality is most important. Use inline with proper documentation warning about writing to `_interal_parameter`. If user writes to it anyway, it's their own fault. If single function call can make things not work properly, you can expect at least some level of competence from library users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the only way to make data private is to hide it in your compilation unit.
This either by using static variable (if the variable is global) or by defining the struct in the compilation unit where it will be used.

You can then declare a non-static function that returns the value either by value or by const reference (using a const pointer). This will force you to create a normal function. Inline will not help because the variable is hidden in the compilation unit.

If the overhead of the function is too high you will be forced to declare the variable as non-static (or to declare your struct). In such a case, there is nothing that will stop your user changing the variable.

There might be a third way, and that will be to declare your variable static and then create a non-static const pointer to the variable that will be exposed outside the function. In such a case, the user could still potentially modify using a cast.

Comment: Your latter solution could be the one I think :)

Answer (score 2):

[c](/questions/tagged/c) does not have good ways of encapsulation.

Real encapsulation can only be achieved by making the variable `static`, and accessing it with a non-inline getter. This will always return a copy of the said variable.

Your second version is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why is the second version undefined behavior?

Comment: 1. The code will not compile. It's missing a definition. 2. Declaration and definition have to match. 3. You can't cast const away. 4. Strict aliasing.

Comment: It is also possible to achieve true private encapsulation by using "opaque type". This will also allow you do use multiple instances of the class. (Downside is that you have to implement an internal memory pool for every class, since malloc isn't used in properly designed embedded systems.)

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I omitted that, because of dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why it would be expensive to use a real getter function. It rather sounds as if your compiler is not doing inlining properly. Also, the ineffectiveness of a function call overhead is often greatly exaggerated, unless you are using some ancient MCU architecture.

The optimal is of course:

```
//lib.c
int get parameter (void)
{
  return parameter;
}
```

Alternatively, if the function call is really too expensive and you can't find out a way to fix inlining, the getter could return a `const int*`. Use a local pointer variable in the caller and then only call the getter once.

Please note that using `int` is almost certainly incorrect practice on any embedded system. Instead use the smallest type that makes sense. Does it have to be signed? It really doesn't make sense to say "my application is so real-time critical that I can't even call functions" and then dump a sloppy `int` in the code.

You should avoid `extern const` unless the variable is a true read-only variable (like a constant in flash memory).

Comment: I am working on a 266MHz CPU where a cycle is 3.75 ns. Our working cycle is 10us which allows us only 2600 assembly instructions. A function call breaks the pipeline and causes a delay of about 14 instructions. An inlined getter is only 1 instruction. So yes it is expensive to use a real getter function.

Comment: Good point about `int`. Of course I am using `int32_t` in this case.

Comment: @nowox 2600 instructions is a lot! Though as you have already realized yourself, getting inlining to work is the best solution.

Comment: @Lundin Inlining will cause the variable to be visible.

Comment: @Lundin it's a lot only if you are not already using 2599 instructions (and you cannot change the architecture for the next 10 Years) :(

Comment: In what architecture does 1 instruction still equals 1 cycle? It's not even true for really simple architectures like zilogs z80.

Comment: @Leandros look at SHARC processors such as the [ADSP-21371](http://www.analog.com/en/products/processors-dsp/sharc/adsp-21371.html)

Comment: @nowox Then don't use 2599 instructions :P On a serious note, function calls is not where I would start looking when I want to reduce the number of instructions.